# .NET Task executed in one Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, task, culture

May I rely on the fact a `Task` is always executed in one thread? It can be any, but it should be the same for the whole body, as I need the thread's `Culture` to be set properly.

```
Task bind = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

    // do some asp.net binding stuff with automatic
    // date formatting

    gridView.DataSource = table;
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

If I can't, is there a parameter or so to get this behaviour?

Cheers, Matthias

Comment: I'm not convinced that data-binding on a different thread is going to play nicely... not least, the http-context will have evaporated

Comment: Good point, didn't know that. I refactored the code a bit so that the data is received asynchronously and bound in a synchronous way. That's the proper way to go, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but only if you have something else useful to do while it is being fetched. i.e. "start async", "do something else", "join async", "data bind" is fine, but "start async", "join async", "data bind" is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the task body is executing in one thread except the case when you starting subtasks or explicitly creating other threads (Thread, ThreadPool, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the code specified for any particular task will be executed on one thread - but continuations may not be. It would be extremely hard to write valid code if tasks were thread-agile *within the body of the task* so I'm pretty sure you're okay.

On the other hand, your code *may* end up being cleaner if you use the culture explicitly wherever it's relevant. That may not be feasible depending on the ASP.NET side of things, but it's worth considering if possible.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried passing a Culture explicitly, but I found no way (`DataSource` setter, `DataBind` method). However, I agree this would be the most elegant way.